# Go handling JSON Responses and Requests

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm relatively new to Go, and while I have a pretty good grasp on understanding most of it so far, I can't exactly figure out how JSON is supposed to be handled.

So let's say I have an access token on the front end. I want to pass it go and want to make a request to an API to validate it.

This is the json being passed to the backend:

```
{
   "accessToken": "xxxxxx"
}


type test_struct struct {
    AccessToken string `json:"accessToken"`
}

func validateFacebookLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var t test_struct
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tokenCheck := "xxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    q := req.URL.Query()

    q.Add("input_token", t.AccessToken)
    q.Add("access_token", tokenCheck)
    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    resp, err := http.Get(req.URL.String())
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    fmt.Println(bodyString);
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"message": "FINE"})
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)

}
```

All documentation I can find seems to indicate that a struct should be created for all JSON responses/requests (unless I'm misunderstanding). Isn't that kind of inconvenient? What if I have an incredibly large nested JSON response? Do I have to create struct of the COMPLETE response?

Is the method I'm using above with ioutil bad practice? Where I could just pass back an entire string representation and manage decoding it on the front-end?

I guess my main question is, when should I be assign my JSON to a struct? What are considered the best practices? If I intent on just returning the response immediately to the front end, is there any point it?

And assuming I do want to maintain the data on the back end, is there any "better" method for handling large responses?

Comment: "All documentation I can find seems to indicate that a struct should be created for all JSON responses/requests" - where do you see this? It's absolutely not required. The default for a JSON object is a `map[string]interface{}`. But structs are generally a lot easier to work with, including for large responses (really, *especially* for large, deeply-nested responses, to avoid a ton of checks and assertions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you'll want to simply utilize json.Unmarshal. This usecase works most of the time:

```
var myClient = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
    r, err := myClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}

foo := Foo{}
getJson("http://example.com", &foo2)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", foo)
```

However, if you're truly working with a large dataset, check out https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder_Decode_stream

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const jsonStream = `
    [
        {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Knock knock."},
        {"Name": "Sam", "Text": "Who's there?"},
        {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Go fmt."},
        {"Name": "Sam", "Text": "Go fmt who?"},
        {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Go fmt yourself!"}
    ]
`
    type Message struct {
        Name, Text string
    }
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))

    // read open bracket
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", t, t)

    // while the array contains values
    for dec.More() {
        var m Message
        // decode an array value (Message)
        err := dec.Decode(&m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", m.Name, m.Text)
    }

    // read closing bracket
    t, err = dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", t, t)

}
```

This will allow you to work in a more memory efficient way.

To more of your question:

1. Do I have to unmarshal to a full response struct? - Not really, you only have to define what you want to use in the struct, the rest will be ignored
2. Are you doing it right? - You're not doing anything inherently wrong?

If there's something I didn't answer, please let me know.

**Edit:** To your usage of `ioutil.ReadAll` - Generally speaking, you'll want to unmarshal into a struct so you can actually *use* the data, and benefit from type safety via your structs. If you literally just need the string, what you're doing is fine, but usually that's not the case.